# How to reset a bound textbox text using triggers

Tags: wpf, templates, triggers, textbox

I'm trying to design a custom TextBox control which has a clear button to let the user rest the TextBox text just like the metro style textboxes.

In the ControlTemplate triggers I have a trigger to do the job.

```
    <Trigger SourceName="ClearButton" Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Trigger>
```

I should say it works fine unless when the TextProperty of the TextBox is bound to a string property of a model for example. In such a situation the Text does not reset by clicking on the Clear button.

I have no idea what the problem might be and how to solve it.

Please help. thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why use a Trigger? It would make a lot more sense to have a click handler in the code for your custom TextBox. That is the correct convention for creating custom controls. When you set Text to null, you are not updating the binding, but replacing it with a new value.

Comment: Thanks it worked. please post your answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a Trigger? It would make a lot more sense to have a click handler in the code for your custom TextBox. That is the correct convention for creating custom controls. When you set Text to null, you are not updating the binding, but replacing it with a new value.